# Spring security Authentication on Java EE controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a webServer which has a web interface where the user is authenticated using Spring security but I need to use the same engine to authenticate a user on a login request from my mobile apps and I need to authenticate them, I've been looking at the authentication classes but I can't seem to get them right its the first time I'm doing this and I hope that someone can help me with this because I am kind of lost

```
@Post
@Path("/mobile/session")
public void login(String username, String password) {
    Usuario usuario = usuarioService.loadByUserName(username);
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePassAuthToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(usuario,EncriptarMD5.encriptar(password));
    Authentication auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(usernamePassAuthToken);
    if(auth.isAuthenticated()){
        result.use(Results.json()).from(RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSessionId().toString(), "token").serialize();
        
    } else {
        result.use(Results.http()).setStatusCode(401);
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following Exception

br.com.caelum.vraptor.InterceptionException: exception raised, check root cause for details: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.ExecuteMethodInterceptor.intercept(ExecuteMethodInterceptor.java:96)
at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:54)
at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.LazyInterceptorHandler.execute(LazyInterceptorHandler.java:61)
at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.ParametersInstantiatorInterceptor.intercept(ParametersInstantiatorInterceptor.java:93)
at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.LazyInterceptorHandler.execute(LazyInterceptorHandler.java:59)
at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
at br.com.otgmobile.trackgoweb.util.CustomInterceptor.intercept(CustomInterceptor.java:24)
at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:54)
at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:56)
at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.FlashInterceptor.intercept(FlashInterceptor.java:83)
at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:54)
at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.ExceptionHandlerInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionHandlerInterceptor.java:71)
at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:54)
at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.InstantiateInterceptor.intercept(InstantiateInterceptor.java:48)
at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:54)
at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.ResourceLookupInterceptor.intercept(ResourceLookupInterceptor.java:69)
at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:54)
at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.EnhancedRequestExecution.execute(EnhancedRequestExecution.java:44)
at br.com.caelum.vraptor.VRaptor$1.insideRequest(VRaptor.java:91)
at br.com.caelum.vraptor.ioc.spring.SpringProvider.provideForRequest(SpringProvider.java:58)
at br.com.caelum.vraptor.VRaptor.doFilter(VRaptor.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.sitemesh.webapp.contentfilter.ContentBufferingFilter.bufferAndPostProcess(ContentBufferingFilter.java:169)
at org.sitemesh.webapp.contentfilter.ContentBufferingFilter.doFilter(ContentBufferingFilter.java:126)
at org.sitemesh.config.ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter.doFilter(ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter.java:163)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:147)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:931)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials

Comment: What is the real problem with your code? It does not work as expected?

Comment: I am testing it right now it actualy dies not work spring security rejects my requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the one piece you are missing is after you authenticate pass the Authentication to the SecurityContextHolder to attach it to the thread.

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

Also when authenticating do not pass the encrypted value to the Auth token.

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePassAuthToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(usuario,password);
```

The authentication manager will take care of encrypting it for you.

Comment: I don't think you need to encrypt your password.  I am positive that the authentication will do that for you.  I will update my answer to add that part.